# Error code when reaching maximum number of registered sip users for credential list

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

What error code is returned when for registration when the maximum number of sip users per credential list (1000) is already registered, and we tried to register more?
We need to know how to handle this case, so that a new credential list can be automatically created for future sip user registrations.
Thanks.
We create (register) a sip user this way:

```
Credential.creator(credentialListSid, username, password).create()
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with writing a script and generating 1001 credentials to fill up the list, which finally revealed that the error code is 21242 with message: The number of Credentials per list cannot exceed 1000
The error code doesn't exist in the Twilio documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21242 (at the moment of writing this)...